# How to run a Gradle task on a compiled jar without having its sources?

Tags: java, docker, gradle, junit, build.gradle

I have a compiled jar with JUnit tests that I want to run from a docker container.

I want to do it with a Gradle task.

First, I will compile the jar and copy it with all its dependencies to a Gradle-based image.
(Or I can create a fat jar which will contain all the third party compiled to a .class).

Then I want to run the task - this task will only run tests according to a test name, JUnit tag, etc.

Is it possible to run a Gradle task on a compiled jar without having its sources?

What should I include in this image beside the gradle.build file for it to work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

***Gradle fetch transitive dependencies and run its tests in test process by default***, so you can use this feature in your case.

> Note that abstract classes are not executed. In addition, be aware that Gradle scans up the inheritance tree into jar files on the test classpath. So if those JARs contain test classes, they will also be run.

[Gradle tests detection document.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:test_detection)

Here is how to do it in your case :

1. Create an empty Gradle project and apply the java  plugin.
2. import the test dependencies tools with the needed scopes in the dependencies section.
3. import myApp.jar as a local dependency.
4. Configure the test task (add needed properties and args).
5. Run Gradle test with the specific properties.

build.gradle example :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
 
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
 
dependencies {
// just examples change with needed unit tests dependencies
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2')
    testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2')
// the target jar file    
    compile file("/myApp.jar")

}
project.ext.testName =  project.hasProperty("testName") ? 
     project.property("testName") : "*"

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
filter {
    //include specific method in any of the tests
    includeTestsMatching "$testName"
}
}
```

Now the Gradle test command will run the target tests in  myApp.jar.
For more information about it check the [Testing in Java & JVM projects official Gradle documents](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html)